# Validating label content equal to null or string.Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I'm trying to check if the value of a label is equal to `null, " ", string.Empty`, but every time I run through my coding, I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my coding:

```
if (lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content.ToString() == "") //Error here
{
    MessageBox.Show("A Supplier was selected with no Email Address. Please update the Supplier's Email Address", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    return;
}
```

How can I check if the string value inside my label is equal to null? I might be missing something simple, if so please ignore my incompetence :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
if (lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content.ToString() == "")
```

To

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((string) lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content)
```

When `lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content` is actually `null` you can of course not call `ToString` on it as it will cause a `NullReferenceException`. However the static `IsNullOrEmpty`-method takes respect on this and returns `true` if `Content` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I still have one small issue with your coding. I still get the error _The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments_, and when I use `.ToString`, I receive the same error as my original question

Comment: `Content` obviously returns `object` instead of `string`. However you can assume that the content actually IS a string, so instead of calling `ToString` you may simply cast it to string.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that was a good coding race, you are the deserved winner. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C#6.0 This will do

```
if(lblSupplierEmailAddress?.Content?.ToString() == "")
```

Else if the `lblSupplierEmailAddress` always exists, you could simply do:

```
if(lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content?.ToString() == "")
```

The equivalent code would be:

```
if(lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content != null)
    if (lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content.ToString() == ""){
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment man! But I still receive an error the same as HimBromBeere's answer. I get the error The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments, and when I use .ToString, I receive the same error as my original question

Comment: @CareTaker22 seems like your Content is an object, wait I will change my answer

Comment: Thanks for the effort to your answer. Yours works as well, but HimBromBeere posted his answer just a bit before you ;)

Comment: @CareTaker22 yes, he was really fast! too bad for me... ;) but glad that you could solve your issue nevertheless :) [edit: yes he was faster ;)]

Comment: However you also handle the (impropable) case that `Content` contains anything different but a string, you´ve earned the +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( null != lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content 
    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblSupplierEmailAddress.Content.ToString() )
```